# are gfortran and g95 both still supported?

Tags: gfortran, g95

I have heard that g95 is no longer active. Which compiler is now the appropriate one to use (I would be grateful for an up-to-date overview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2010-12-29, the project appears to be dead. There were no updates to the project's blog since the middle of August 2010 and rumors of Andy Vaught's move to competing compiler vendor PathScale have been going around[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G95), but nothing has been confirmed. [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G95)]

gfortran however is still regularly updated, and I see questions regarding it popping up regularly in here.

My personal opinion, regards g95, is that it's just a temporary setback, and that it will be continually developed. I know a few contributors, and although they have no say on the matter, it is a general opinion that this is just a temporery setback until a new "leader" pops up or Vaught speaks up.

Comment: If I recall correctly, a couple of weeks (months?) ago, there was an interesting discussion on the gfortran mailing list, where someone from Patshcale (I think) was enquiring about the copyright of some of the code of the gcc fortran compiler, before the split into g95 and gfortran. It appeared to me as if they were seeing if they could safely incorporate g95 code into their codebase. I think the person also talked about Andy as if they were current colleagues. Now, be warned that I'm writing this all from memory and I'm nothing but an outside observer who knows nothing about actual goings on.

Comment: The discussion I was referring to can be found here: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2011-06/msg00141.html

Comment: @eriktous - Thanks for the link. Interesting. I also am nothing but an observer regarding gnu fortrans (both of them), but like from time to time check in to see how things are going. gfortran/g95 are both projects not to be ignored, in terms of advancement in regards to fortran language features. They, one could say, are even putting some commercial compilers to shame.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2017 G95 has been essentially dead for many years with just a few small updates in recent years which did not contain any new features.

It still continues to be a useful compiler if your program does not use too many modern (2003 and beyond) Fortran features.

The last update on the website is dated "Feb 17" without year and claims to be  a major overhaul of coarrays (whir are not that important to most users). The missing year seems to be 2013 (after checking archive.org).